# If f is continous and exist real numbers show that $f(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

If $f$ is continous in $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ and exist real numbers $\alpha \not= \beta$ such that

$$\alpha\int_{a}^{c} f(x) dx + \beta\int_{c}^{b} f(x) dx  =0$$

for all $c \in [a,b]$ show that $f (x)=0$ for all $x \in [a,b].$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to insert the alpha and beta into their respective integrals and then add the integrals together. Then, inside the integral, I factorized f (x) and took the term that is a constant (α + b) from the integral. Then I divide both sides by that constant (α + b).
So, I have $ \int_{a} ^ {b} f (x) dx = 0 $

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(c)=\alpha\int\limits_a^c f(x) dx + \beta \int\limits_c^b f(x) dx$, $g$ is derivable and since $f$ is continuous,  $g'(c)=(\alpha-\beta)f(c)=0$ since $g$ is constant. Since $\alpha\neq \beta$, we deduce that $f(c)=0, c\in [a,b]$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $c\in[a,b]$.

$$\alpha\int_a^cf+\beta\int_c^bf=0$$
$$\implies$$
$$(\alpha-\beta)\int_a^cf=-\beta\int_a^bf=Cte$$
By differentiation, it gives
$$(\alpha-\beta)f(c)=0$$
and $$f(c)=0$$

Comment: Why can I say that it is a constant?

Comment: @Esteb It doesn't depend on $ c$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\int\limits_a^x f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=F(x)$, then it's given that
$$\alpha F(c)+\beta\left(F(b)-F(c)\right)=0$$
$$(\alpha-\beta) F(c)=-\beta F(b)$$
$$F(c)=-\frac{\beta}{(\alpha-\beta) } F(b)$$
So $F(x)$ is a constant thus $f(x)=0$.